# How do I use Swift 3 scheduleRepeating?

Tags: swift, swift3

It has something to do with `DispatchSourceTimer`, but I can't get anywhere.

This gives me an error about "ambiguous reference":

```
DispatchSourceTimer.scheduleRepeating(deadline:.now(), interval:.milliseconds(delay), leeway:.milliseconds(1))
```

## My solution

The problem was to do with type confusion. Thanks matt for pointing me in the right direction. Here is my full result.

```
private var queueNo = 0
@discardableResult  func repeater(_ delay:Int, _ closure:(()->())) -> (()->()) {
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "repeater\(queueNo)", attributes: [])
    queueNo += 1
    let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: [], queue: queue)
    timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(delay), interval: .milliseconds(delay), leeway: .milliseconds(1))
    timer.setEventHandler {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: closure)
    }
    timer.resume()
    return {
        timer.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: for starter, i really was calling the static function when i needed an instantiated `DispatchSource.timer(...)`. secondly my `delay` used to be an Int64 which caused the type issues.

Comment: Looks like this has changed in Beta 4

Comment: Hm. Need to look into that.

Comment: any luck? I'm running into the same problem and the docs are completely empty.

Comment: my solution is listed above. but I haven't double checked it. is it not good?

Comment: The key thing is to make sure the parameters are Int rather than Int64, in my case I had to use something like this to resolve the ambiguous reference error: `timer.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now() + .seconds(Int(interval)), interval: .seconds(Int(interval)), leeway: .seconds(Int(leeway)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Swift 3
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}

func update() {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.
NSTimer and GCD Timers are different things.
GCD Timers give much more control on the way it executes, can be prioritized, are more battery friendly...